# Wagtail filter page-childs-elements on the basis of logged-in user's permissions

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am working on a small site using Wagtail. This site is all about a "mainpage" and several "subpages". So far it is pretty simple! But, depending on what group the user (not admin) is in, the right subpages should show up!

See the following setup (minimized), to get an idea of what I am talking about.

If I set permissions on ToolKitPart (like requiring explicit user-login and group-membership), then the following is happening:

- when going to the page using the fully qualified path, the user is requested to login and, in the case of insufficient rights, the user will not see the content!
- when going to the ToolkitIndex-Page, all children are displayed, including the ones the user never should see, without the need to be logged in or being a member of a certain group.

  ```
  class ToolkitIndex(Page):
      def get_context(self, request):
          # Update context to include only published posts, ordered by reverse-chron
          context = super().get_context(request)
          blogpages = self.get_children().live().order_by('-first_published_at')
          context['pages'] = blogpages    
          return context

  class ToolkitPart(Page):
      body = StreamField([
          ('staff', MpStaff()),
          ('news', MpNews()),
          ('stuff', MpStuff()),
          ('teditor', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
          ('reditor', blocks.RawHTMLBlock()),
      ], blank=True)

      content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
          StreamFieldPanel('body'),
      ]

  class MpNews(blocks.StructBlock):
      head = blocks.TextBlock(required=True, help_text='Schlagzeile')
      lead = blocks.TextBlock(required=False, help_text='Einleitung')
      body = blocks.RichTextBlock(required=True, help_text='Inhalt')
      image = ImageChooserBlock(required=False)

      type = blocks.ChoiceBlock(
          choices=[('default', 'Standard'),
               ('highlight', 'Hervorgehoben'),
               ], required=True)

      class Meta:
          template = 'home/mparts/toolkit_news.html'
          icon = 'code'
  ```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Wagtail permissions propagate down the page tree, but I don't yet understand what you're trying to do.  Are there any fields defined on ToolkitIndex, or is what you have posted the full declaration for that class?  Also, please post the templates (if any) for ToolkitIndex and ToolkitPart.

Comment: This is simple. ToolkitIndex has many childs. Childs are protected due eleveted righs. And the ToolkitIndex.get_context() returns alls childs despite eleveted rights needed. The REAL Question is how to serve content for the particuar usergroup, the current user is logged on.

Comment: So is an individual blogpage actually a ToolkitPart?

Comment: Y. Petty much like that. Not so different

Comment: Did you go to Settings in the Wagtail admin and select the user group and then assign the appropriate rights for that user group to ToolkitIndex?

Comment: Not exactly. I tried to solve this with settings permissions on childs (toolkitPart). I am very sorry, but this kind of topic is kind of weird to describe. 

One MotherNode own multible Childs. Some of the childs should be visible to a certain user, some not - depending on the rights the users owns.

When using route direct to the childs all works just fine. But when using the get_context method rights seems to be ignored. Is there a way to filter by user-rights / group rights?

Comment: I would think not because group rights are assigned by object type.  Perhaps you could create proxy models to ToolkitPart and assign group rights to each proxy model.  I have recently done this in a Wagtail project, but I would add a caveat:  for some reason, not all proxy models are shown in the Wagtail admin.  See this StOflw question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701676/wagtail-modeladmin-several-sections-for-custom-user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188234/discussion-between-dan-swain-and-r4r3devaut).

Comment: Gasman´s answer was right - and exactly what i am looking for. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've set these permissions up using Wagtail's [private pages](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/privacy.html) feature, these are stored in the [`PageViewRestriction`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/dbb7ec77b30a7bd55201e069603b1ae3e6aa3b90/wagtail/core/models.py#L1915) model. Unfortunately Wagtail doesn't currently provide a way to apply these permission checks against anything other than the current page request, so you'd have to recreate this logic yourself to filter a queryset to the user's view permissions. This would be something like (untested):

```
from django.db.models import Q

class ToolkitIndex(Page):
    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        blogpages = self.get_children().live().order_by('-first_published_at')

        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            blogpages = blogpages.public()  # only pages with no view restrictions at all

        else:
            blogpages = blogpages.filter(
                # pages with no view restrictions
                Q(view_restrictions__isnull=True)
                # pages restricted to any logged-in user
                | Q(view_restrictions__restriction_type='login')
                # pages restricted by group
                | Q(view_restrictions__restriction_type='groups', view_restrictions__groups__in=request.user.groups.all())
            )
```

Disclaimers:

- This doesn't account for pages that are protected by a shared password
- To be fully correct, we'd need to account for the fact that view restrictions propagate down the tree (and so a subpage may still be restricted even if it doesn't have a view restriction record directly attached to it); however, we're only looking at immediate children of the current page (which they evidently *do* have access to...) so that issue doesn't come up here.
- `PageViewRestriction` is not a public Wagtail API and may change in future releases - in particular, see [RFC 32](https://github.com/wagtail/rfcs/pull/32) for a proposed change that may happen in the fairly near future.