# Wagtail: How to use view_restrictions in ModelAdmin to filter query set?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am trying to manage the access to certain `PageModel` pages in the Wagtail admin via [Privat Pages](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/privacy.html#private-pages) and the associated [`PageViewRestriction`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/dbb7ec77b30a7bd55201e069603b1ae3e6aa3b90/wagtail/core/models.py#L1915) model, using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629835/wagtail-filter-page-childs-elements-on-the-basis-of-logged-in-users-permissions?rq=1) as a reference:

```
class MyAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = MyPage
    [ ... ]
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        user = request.user
        [ ... ]
        elif user.is_client:
            return qs.filter(
                Q(view_restrictions__restriction_type='groups', view_restrictions__groups__in=user.groups.all())
            )
        return None
```

Nothing returns so I checked in the shell:

```
qs = MyPage.objects.all()
qs.first().get_view_restrictions()
>>> <QuerySet [<PageViewRestriction: PageViewRestriction object (2)>]>

qs.first().get_view_restrictions().first().groups.all()
>>> <QuerySet [<Group: MyGroup>]>
```

So the restrictions are set but trying the same query as above returns an empty qs:

```
my_user.groups.all()
>>> <QuerySet [<Group: MyGroup>]

qs.filter(Q(view_restrictions__restriction_type='groups', view_restrictions__groups__in=my_user.groups.all()))
>>> <PageQuerySet []>
```

Something that confuses me further is the fact that the `view_restrictions` field on the `MyPage` instance is empty but the `get_view_restrictions` method returns the expected object.

```
qs.first().specific.view_restrictions.all()
>>> <QuerySet []>

qs.first().specific.get_view_restrictions()
>>> <QuerySet [<PageViewRestriction: PageViewRestriction object (2)>]>
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

I got some feedback from Wagtail’s side and it seems to be "a bit tricky" at the moment to archive what I want. `view_restrictions` is empty because the restrictions are set on an ancestor page and propagate down the tree.

There is a [PR](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/6300) in the works though, that addresses my use case